# Why is the region for an empty language "US"?

Tags: go

I am using the official/unofficial language package and have this:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

func main() {
    reg, _ := language.Tag{}.Region()
    log.Println(reg.Canonicalize()) // US
}
```

I was expecting "ZZ". Why is it "US"? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Looks like US is the default.

Comment: that's my question...I don't see where in the code it says that and why they do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the method [tag{}.Region()](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/language/language.go#L452) you'll see that if region is not specified it tries to add tags and sets the likelihood to low. [addTags()](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/2bf8f2a19ec09c670e931282edfe6567f6be21c9/language/match.go) If you look at the implementation for addTags() you'll see

```
if t.lang == 0 {
  t.lang = _en // default language
}
```

where the default language is set to English. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If tag's language is not defined (zero by default), then it just get the first value from `likelyLang` [array](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/language/match.go#L220).

```
    x := likelyLang[t.lang]
    ...
    if x.region != 0 {
        t.setUndefinedScript(scriptID(x.script))
        t.setUndefinedRegion(regionID(x.region))
    }
```

And it has [_US](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/language/tables.go#L1002) (0x134) region code (surprise). After that it copies region to the input tag.

P.S. @reticentroot's answer is about the same. Didn't see it during investigation.